# Additional MX record for subdomain

Tags: dns, amazon-route53, mx-record

Please, help me with one problem - how to add a MX records for a subdomain (we use Route 53 as dns)?

Example:
We have MX records for our domain.com with Gsuite servers as values - all works fine. Now we want add a MX records for subdomain news.domain.com to make it as alias to the main domain in Gsuite.

Question: How i should create MX records for subdomain? I should put same MX server values as main domain?

Thanks for Your support in advance!

Comment: Did I answer your question? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers for what to do when someone answers your question. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

> How i should create MX records for subdomain? I should put same MX server values as main domain?

Yes. The host value in an MX record points to another record (usually an A record).

Here's the example from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MX_record):

```
Domain          TTL   Class    Type  Priority      Host
example.com.        1936    IN  MX  10         onemail.example.com
example.com.        1936    IN  MX  10         twomail.example.com
```

In your case, it would look something like this:

```
domain.com.             1936    IN  MX  10         gsuite-mail-server-here
news.domain.com.        1936    IN  MX  10         gsuite-mail-server-here
```